# Create Thread within a thread - good practice?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it good practice to start a thread within a thread? I have searched around but have not found much information.

I have a TimerTask which gets a list of users every day at a certain time. I then want to get some data about the user, but this requires user input. Because it requires user input, I don't want my TimerTask thread to be blocked in the case of users not responding. For example, the first user in the list may not respond in X amount of time, I don't want to wait X amount of time until I ask the second user for their data, and so on. So within my TimerTask, I create and start a new Thread to get the data. This way, in Y amount of time, if i have recieved some data (but not all) I can still do other things instead of waiting for every one to complete.

Is it good practice to do the above? Are there any better solutions?

Here is some psudeo code which may help you understand.

```
class UserThread extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.debug("Get a list of members!");
            List<String> users = userManager.getUsers();
            retrieveInitialData(users);
        }

        public void retrieveInitialData(List<String> users) {
            for(String user : users) {
                new Thread(new GetData(user)).start();
            }
        }

        addToSuccessList(String user) {
            synchronized(successList) {
                successList.add(user);
            }
        }

        addToFailureList(String user) {
            synchronized(failureList) {
                failureList.add(user);
            }
        }

        class GetData extends Thread {

            String userID;

            public GetData(String user) {
            this.userID = user;
            }

            public void run() {
            try {
                dataManager.getData(user);
                addToSuccessList(user);
            } catch(Execption e) {
                addToFailureList(user);
            }

        }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Any thread can start a new thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224670/threads-within-threads-in-java have you looked at this?

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth Thanks for that, I missed that somehow!

Comment: If a thread cannot create another thread, what could, (other than the OS kernel loader/bootstrap)?

Comment: @MartinJames I know a thread can create another thread, but I was wondering whether it was good practice or if there was a better solution.

Comment: What Martin James is aiming at is that you generally always create a thread from another thread. That "main application code" you have in your mind is also a thread, just not one that you created. In that respect there is nothing wrong with it, as long as it is functionally a good idea. And that is something you should answer yourself. You know you can. But is it a good idea?

Comment: I am trying to catch an exception inside my thread and let the thread continue - but it dosen´t. When I make a thread A that creates and start thread B - the exception I catch in thread B stops both threads. Why is that? Anybody knows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better approach would be to use a `ThreadPool` and a `ScheduledExecutorService`. Starting a thread from a thread is not inherently bad (after all everything runs inside a thread so you need to do that somewhere!) but may indicate a flaw in your design.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will give ThreadPool a read up!

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor solves a different problem than Thread.  A ThreadPoolExecutor is an ExecutorService that owns a number of Threads, and uses them to execute tasks.  The difference is that the run() method of a task usually does one thing, and then returns.  The run() method that we give to a naked Thread usually has a loop that runs indefinitely (e.g., waiting for incoming connections on a port, or something like).

Answer (score 2):

In Java all threads are owned by the process, and it doesn't matter from where they are started. So there's nothing wrong with your code.