# Is it a good practice to use threads within another threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

According to the title,look at this code:

```
Thread outer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread inner1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //some statements and other inner threads
                    }
                });

                Thread inner2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //some statements and other inner threads
                    }
                });

                //some statements and other inner threads
            }
        });
```

So, is it a good practice to use multithreading like this?

Regards

Comment: Please try to stick to 1 question per question.

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry... i just didn't want to send 3 posts. still, if it's not good, i'll edit it and send 2 more post. should i do it?

Comment: Well currently the question(s) is a bit too big to answer properly.

Comment: @Kayaman ok. i'll fix it now...

Comment: I think the main answer here is: it depends. This design is not bad practice per se, it totally depends on what you are using it for...

Comment: @NickL yes, but i'm sure any problem can be solved in several ways and it needs a lot of experience to gain that ability which led you to the best way

Comment: @HMD there almost never is a 'best' way. It's all a matter of coding style, personal preference and context. The answer to whether this by definition is bad practice or not, is no. I can think of many examples where this code would be just fine. I can also think of many cases where this code would be terrible.

Comment: And in a way, you are actually always creating a thread from some other thread. The main method of your program is called on the `main` thread. From there you start and run other threads. Threads are not nested, they run in parallel, no matter where you call them from.

Comment: @NickL thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There are no inner Threads in any programming language. Threads are just objects with a `run()` method with the feature that several Threads can run at the same time (concurrently).

In your example, you create two Threads inside the `run()` method of a Thread. That is not a problem since you can create Objects in any context.

If you want to use the Threads, you have to call `outer.start()`, `inner1.start()` and `inner2.start()` after creating the Threads, otherwise they aren't executed. Again, that's absolutely fine because it doesn't matter in which context a Thread is started; all Threads are treated equally by the Java Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1):

according to Q1 "is it good". It's correct, however does not make much sense to create a threat only to create another threads.

Also, keep in mind, that creating a Thread object is relatively expensive operation.
You have `//some statements and other inner threads` comment in your code. Consider using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to avoid creating many Threads manually.

Answer (score 1):

This [Java Code Geeks](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/concurrency-best-practices.html#threads) article on concurrency has a few recommendations for you. I would suggest you read it in its entirety but here are two important snippets:

> Typically, it is not recommended to directly create and manage threads using the instances of Thread class...

and this:

> Creating new threads in Java is easy, but managing them is really
>   tough. Java standard library provides extremely useful abstractions in
>   the form of executors and thread pools targeted to simplify threads
>   management.
>
> Essentially, in its simplest implementation, thread pool creates and
>   maintains a list of threads, ready to be used right away.
>   Applications, instead of spawning new thread every time, just borrows
>   the one (or as many as needed) from the pool. Once borrowed thread
>   finishes its job, it is returned back to the pool, and becomes
>   available to pick up next task.
>
> Though it is possible to use thread pools directly, Java standard
>   library provides an [executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) façade which has a set of factory method
>   to create commonly used thread pool configurations.

Threads have a lot of states to manage, which is also identified in the article:

- **NEW**: A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
- **RUNNABLE**: A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
- **BLOCKED**: A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
- **WAITING**: A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
- **TIMED_WAITING**: A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
- **TERMINATED**: A thread that has exited is in this state.

Here are additional considerations from the below answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224670/threads-within-threads-in-java):

1. [Consider non-blocking I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224720/2356554)

   > Yes, you can launch as many threads as you want, but that's probably
   >   not the best way to go. It's much better to use the non-blocking API's
   >   so that you can start execution of some external call and the calling
   >   thread can immediately start doing something else without waiting on
   >   the socket/database call to come back. Then, when the socket/database
   >   call comes back, a callback is triggered to finish that processing.
   >
   > Non-blocking I/O can provide far superior CPU utilization since you're
   >   just triggering calls and registering callbacks and not having to try
   >   to balance the "right" number of concurrent threads which are mostly
   >   just sleeping anyways.
2. [Consider thread hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225258/2356554)

> Is the hierarchy important?
>
> You're probably better off using an ExecutorService with a cached
>   thread pool.
>
> That way you can pool threads instead of creating lots (which is
>   expensive). ExecutorServices also provide other cool things, and using
>   Callables / Runnables with them is probably much easier to test than
>   mucking about with threads on your own.

Comment: Re, "_Typically, it is not recommended to directly create and manage threads using the instances of Thread class_."  That's bad advice IMO.  If you want a long-running, specialized thread, then instantiating `Thread` is the simplest way to get one.  Simpler often == better,  though, there _are_ cases where you might want to use a `ThreadFactory` instead.  Now, we could argue about whether or not you should _want_ a long-running, specialized thread, but that is a different topic for discussion.

Comment: I don't know if "it's simpler" holds enough weight when considering the tradeoffs of thread lifecycle, resource management, durability, monitoring, standardization/legibility, etc. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34373289/2356554) is an interesting answer regarding a single thread vs. the Executor library. Also, straight from Oracle are a [good arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/concurrency/overview.html) for always preferring the concurrency package.

Answer (score 1):

I would not prefer this way because:

*Less readable

*Thread 2 automatically will pick thread 1 priority unless you dont set manually

*Thread scheduler JVM based (like time slices, queuing...) so you dont know when thread 1 will pass the runnable state

*If thread 2 relies on thread 1 you can achieve this target using wait and notify or other new features so it will be more readable